# Recognize if not enough resources during timeframe

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, algorithm, postgresql, search

i need an idea how to solve the following problem.

Lets say i have one group with given timeframe (8:00-12:00) and i can assign resources (people) to it. Each resource can have a custom timeframe (like 9-10, 9-12,8-12 etc.) and could be assigned multiple times.

Tables

### Groups

ID,
TITLE,
START_TIME,
END_TIME,
REQUIRED_PEOPLE:INTEGER

### PeopleAssignments

ID,
USER_ID,
GROUP_ID,
START_TIME,
END_TIME

Now i have the rule that at any given time during the group timeframe that there have to be like like 4 people assigned. Otherwise i want to get a warning.

I am working with ruby & sql (Postgres) here.

is there an elegant way without iterating through the whole timeframe and checking if count(assignments) > REQUIRED_PEOPLE

Comment: what have you made so far? Show your solution so we could tell if it is elegant already

Comment: So far i have an "cheap" approximation. (REQUIRED_PEOPLE * GROUP_DURATION) - SUM(ASSIGNMENT_DURATIONS_FOR_GROUP) but that wont solve the problem when i have ten people assigned for one hour at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with only SQL too (if you are interested in such answers).

[Range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) offers great [functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html) to calculate with.

These solutions will give you rows, when there are sub-ranges, where there is some missing people from a given group (and it will give you which sub-range it is exactly & how many people is missing from the required number).

**The easy way:**

You wanted to try something similar to this. You'll need to pick some interval in which the `count()` is based on (I picked `5 minutes`):

```
select     g.id group_id, i start_time, i + interval '5 minutes' end_time, g.required_people - count(a.id)
from       groups g
cross join generate_series(g.start_time, g.end_time, interval '5 minutes') i
left join  people_assignments a on a.group_id = g.id
where      tsrange(a.start_time, a.end_time) && tsrange(i, i + interval '5 minutes')
group by   g.id, i
having     g.required_people - count(a.id) > 0
order by   g.id, i
```

But note that you won't be able to detect missing sub-ranges, when they are less than `5 minutes`. F.ex. user1 has assignment for `11:00-11:56` and user2 has one for `11:59-13:00`, they will appear to be "in" the group for `11:00-13:00` (so the missing sub-range of `11:56-11:59` will go unnoticed).

*Note*: the more short the interval is (what you've picked) the more precise (and slow!) the results will be.

http://rextester.com/GRC64969

**The hard way**:

You can accumulate the result on-the-fly with [custom aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xaggr.html) or [recursive CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)

```
with recursive r as (
    -- start with "required_people" as "missing_required_people" in the whole range
    select 0 iteration,
           id group_id,
           array[]::int[] used_assignment_ids,
           -- build a json map, where keys are the time ranges
           -- and values are the number of missing people for that range
           jsonb_build_object(tsrange(start_time, end_time), required_people) required_people_per_time_range
    from   groups
    where  required_people > 0
    and    id = 1 -- query parameter
  union all
    select r.iteration + 1,
           r.group_id,
           r.used_assignment_ids || a.assignment_id,
           d.required_people_per_time_range
    from   r
    -- join a single assignment to the previous iteration, where
    -- the assigment's time range overlaps with (at least one) time range,
    -- where there is still missing people. when there are no such time range is
    -- found in assignments, the "recursion" (which is really just a loop) stops
    cross join lateral (
      select     a.id assignment_id, tsrange(start_time, end_time) time_range
      from       people_assignments a
      cross join (select key::tsrange time_range from jsonb_each(r.required_people_per_time_range)) j
      where      a.group_id = r.group_id
      and        a.id <> ALL (r.used_assignment_ids)
      and        tsrange(start_time, end_time) && j.time_range
      limit      1
    ) a
    -- "partition" && accumulate all remaining time ranges with
    -- the one found in the previous step
    cross join lateral (
      -- accumulate "partition" results
      select jsonb_object_agg(u.time_range, u.required_people) required_people_per_time_range
      from   (select key::tsrange time_range, value::int required_people
              from   jsonb_each_text(r.required_people_per_time_range)) j
      cross join lateral (
        select u time_range, j.required_people - case when u && a.time_range then 1 else 0 end required_people
        -- "partition" the found time range with all existing ones, one-by-one
        from   unnest(case
                 when j.time_range @> a.time_range
                 then array[tsrange(lower(j.time_range), lower(a.time_range)), a.time_range, tsrange(upper(a.time_range), upper(j.time_range))]
                 when j.time_range && a.time_range
                 then array[j.time_range * a.time_range, j.time_range - a.time_range]
                 else array[j.time_range]
               end) u
        where not isempty(u)
      ) u
    ) d
),
-- select only the last iteration
l as (
  select   group_id, required_people_per_time_range
  from     r
  order by iteration desc
  limit    1
)
-- unwind the accumulated json map
select     l.group_id, lower(time_range) start_time, upper(time_range) end_time, missing_required_people
from       l
cross join lateral (
  select key::tsrange time_range, value::int missing_required_people
  from   jsonb_each_text(l.required_people_per_time_range)
) j
-- select only where there is still some missing people
-- this is optional, if you omit it you'll also see row(s) for sub-ranges where
-- there is enough people in the group (these rows will have zero,
-- or negative amount of "missing_required_people")
where      j.missing_required_people > 0
```

http://rextester.com/GHPD52861

Comment: thanks for your answer, i think ill go with the easy way. i only allow assignments in 15 minute steps, that should do it

Comment: Hmm we currently use Postgres 9.1 on some machines and i get errors with that solution. I tracked it down to a basic query like `SELECT g.id FROM groups g CROSS JOIN generate_series(g.start_time, g.end_time, interval '5 minutes') i` which works on 9.5 but not 9.1. It complains about invalid table reference g. In general i am not able to use any tables inside that function. Any ideas?

Comment: @Skully that's called a `LATERAL` join and it is supported from 9.3+. You can simulate it on earlier versions, with [correlated subqueries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql). Though 9.1 is getting pretty old, and it doesn't supported anymore (the earliest, still supported version is currently the 9.2 branch). I would highly recommend an update.

Answer (score 0):

In any case you need to query number of assignment in DB. There is no other way to find how many times a group assign to people.

There might be ways to find number of assignment but in the end you have to fire a query to DB.

```
@group = Group.find(id)
if @group.people_assignments.count >= REQUIRED_PEOPLE
  pus 'warning'
end
```

You can add extra column in group that hold information how many times that group assign to people. In this way one query to server reduced.

```
@group = Group.find(id)
if @group.count_people_assigned >= REQUIRED_PEOPLE
  puts 'warning'
end
```

In second case `count_people_assigned` is column so no extra query will execute while in first case `people_assignments` is association so one extra query will fire.

But in second case you have you update group each time you assign group to people. Ultimately extra query. Your choice where you want to reduce query.

My opinion is second case, It will happen rare than first.

Comment: Thanks but its not that simple. I want to make sure that during every second in the timeframe of the group there are always REQUIRED_PEOPLE assigned. Since people can be assigned by a custom timeframe, it wont be done with just counting them